# absolute ignoring parent padding

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and I am trying to create my own dropdown menu on right side.

I Tried below css.But its ignoring parents padding.But when I use `position : relative` Its working fine but its pushing the text contents down.So I want absolute overlay but also Preserve the parent padding.

```
.menu
{
  background:#ccc;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  clear: both;
}
```

Here is the fiddle with html - http://jsfiddle.net/97bqun6s/

P.s: my parent is bootstrap `.container` class whose padding varies for screen sizes.

Comment: Add left:0px; and that should reset the position because at the moment it is being pull to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `position: absolute` on an element then that element will be positioned within its closest 'non static' parent container's content area and padding box. You can refer to the [Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) for reference.

A simple solution would be to say `right: 15px`. This will offset the side-nav from the right to align with the rest of the container.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97bqun6s/1/)

EDIT:

Since the padding of the container is variable this may not be a viable solution.

You could instead add a wrapper div just inside the container

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-wrap">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and position it relative.

```
 .content-wrap {
    position: relative;
 }
```

See updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97bqun6s/2/)

Comment: Hey See my p.s : bootstrap container padding varies for different screensize..Its not fixed to 15px